# Print bibliography in a specific style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I want to display the bibiolgraphy as shown in this figure. 
[image: Figure 1]

I would like to have the year directly after the author's name, and the title of paper without "." What command can I put into the preamble of my .tex file to enforce this?

```
\documentclass {article}   
 \usepackage[round]{natbib}   
 \bibliographystyle{apalike}

  \begin{document}
  \cite{Sampson1989}
  \bibliography{my_bibtex}
  \end{document}
```

My file my_bibtex.bib

```
@article{Sampson1989,
author = {Sampson, R J and Groves, W B},
year = {1989},
title = {Community structure and crime: testing social-disorganization theory},
volume = {94},
number = {4},
journal = {Am J Soc},
pages = {774}
 }
```

What I obtain is:

[image]

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to a compilable minimal working example, so that we can see which documentclass you use, wich bibliography relevant packages you use aund how you cite. Then we can play with your MWE and can help you ...

Comment: Your sample bib entry is missing the `journal` field. Please provide the missing information. There's a comma missing at the end of the `number` field. Separately, the syntax in the author field is almost certainly incorrect; it should probably be `author = {Sampson, R J and Groves, W B},`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to display my references as shown in figure 1: lastname1 firstname1, lastname2 firstname2 (date) Title. This is a style recommended by: Data mining and knowledge discovery journal

Comment: Rather than hack the `apalike` bibliography style to obtain the desired style, I suggest you run the `makebst` utility (part of the `custom-bib` package) to create your very own bespoke bibliography style. The `makebst` utility will pose a number of multiple-choice type questions and will create a bst file that incorporates all of your choices regarding topics such as abbreviating first names, using (or, rather, not using) dots at the end of the abbreviated first and middle names, not italicizing the names of journals, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of obtaining what you want with `biblatex-apa` and some patches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}%
\begin{filecontents*}{apabibli1.bib}
@article{Sampson1989,
author = {Sampson, R J and Groves, W B},
year = {1989},
title = {Community structure and crime: testing social-disorganization theory},
volume = {94},
number = {4},
journal = {Am J Soc},
pages = {774}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{apabibli1.bib}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{author}
{%
\newunit\newblock
}
{%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:apa:last-first}
{%
\addcomma\addlowpenspace\mkbibnamefirst{#3}\isdot
}
{%
\addlowpenspace\mkbibnamefirst{#3}\isdot
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addspace\thinspace}%
\iffieldundef{series}
{}
{\newunit
 \printfield{series}
 \setunit{\addspace}}%
\printfield{volume}%
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
\usebibmacro{issuename}%
\newunit}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace and\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

    \AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
         {\addcomma\space}%
         {\addcomma\space}}}}

    \renewcommand\bibinitperiod{}
\renewcommand\bibinitdelim{}
\renewcommand\bibpagespunct{\addcolon\space}


\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}

\setlength{\bibhang}{1.2em}
\let\cite\parencite

\usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{ colorlinks = true, citecolor = blue,}

\begin{document}

\cite{Sampson1989}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sam Faith: Sorry, I used the preamble of another file to test, and it used the `erewhon` font, which is a recent extension to Adobe Utopia (with true small caps, cyrillic and the like). You can remove it, or replace it with `heuristica` if you have it installed. Or simply remove the whole second line.

Comment: Did you compile exactly the code in my answer?  `\addbibresource` is defined by biblatex. Also, just in case, compile the bibliography with `biber`, or add `backend=bibtex` to the options to biblatex.

Comment: When I compile using bibtex I obtain : The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux I found no \citation
commands---while reading file test.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux (There
were 3 error messages)

Comment: OK, I checked the docs: `biblatex-apa` requires `biber` as backend (it's the default). Can you try with biber? Anyway it has much more functionalities than `bibtex` and understands `utf8`. Don't forget to delete all auxiliary files first.

Comment: In my WinEdt, i haven't the compiler option : biber.

Comment: Which version of WinEdt do you have?

Comment: I have WinEdt 9.0

Comment: OH. Go to `http://www.winedt.org/` and install the `Latexify` menu addition. You'll have `biber` in the `TeX` menu and in the toolbar.

Comment: I have installed the Latexify menu but I haven't the biber in the Tex menu and when I compile using Latexify I have this error : biber.exe could not be found

Comment: Do you have `biber` installed?

Comment: It works now, thank you, but I have two little problems: the first is ,I want that `\cite` gives me a link, for that I used `\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true,
   citecolor    = blue,}` but I have only the date as a link. Moreover, I want to display ciatation like this : (Sampson and Groves 1989). I have used the pakage `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` but it doesn't work , i have an error. Last request, in references, I wnt when I get a new line, the new line is offset by three letters of the first line. in your answer,the word disorganisation must start under letter m.

Comment: @Sam Faith: Take a look at the modified code. I think it's  OK, except for the link colouring, which I don't know how to do.